# Check radio button value if is true or false and show hide div

Tags: jquery, animation, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons that I currently check their value if is 6 or 12 and hide /show the relevant div in my table.

```
<tr>   
   <td>
       <div class="Price6 band" style="display: none;">21.09</div>
       <div class="Price12 band">21.09</div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td>
        <input id="radio1" class="radio" type="radio"  name="price" value="6">
         <label for="radio1">£24.95</label>
          <input id="radio1" class="radio" type="radio" name="price" value="12">
          <label for="radio1">&nbsp;£6.95</label>
      </td>
 </tr>
```

How do I edit my jquery code so it checks for the value of the radio buttons if is true or false rather the number value?

My jquery currently is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='price']").click(function() {//switch bewtween price bands
        var test = $(this).val();

        $("div.band").hide();
        $(".Price" + test).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: should the 2nd set of radio1 (the input and the label) be radio2 ?  with the name still making them a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
$("input").change(function(){
    var test = $(this).val();
    if(test == '6'){
        $(".Price6").show();
        $(".Price12").hide();
    }
    if(test == '12'){
        $(".Price12").show();
        $(".Price6").hide();
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/QsXm5/

**Note:** I changed the #s for the price `div`s that were being shown because in your example they are the same and you cannot tell if a change is occurring.

Comment: Glad to help @george!  If this did the trick, feel free to click the checkmark to let others know its answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "$(this).val()" with "$(this).attr("checked")" that will return "checked" it this radiobutton is selected, or "undefined" if not, then you can use this values to run your script or replace them with true/false if you want.